Microsoft Edge, css "@media print" not working
I need to print the content of an element in my web page, I added this to my CSS sheet so that the content fits the page enterely:
@media print {
    .toPrintData {
        transform: scale(0.65);
    }
}

I open the print preview window using js like this:
var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=650,width=1000'); 
mywindow.document.write(toPrintData);
mywindow.document.close();
mywindow.focus();  
mywindow.print(); 
mywindow.close();

This works on Chrome just fine but Edge won't apply the style.
When debugging and emulating the CSS media type via devTools (in the "Rendering" section, choosing "Print" instead of "No emulation") the style actually applies but when opening the print preview window it doesn't and remains on the "Actual size" default setting and not on the custom 65 one.
I tried putting !important to the css style, using other styles like size, margin, page-break-inside: avoid; or zoom to no avail.
I also tried to apply the style directely in the head tag of the html.

Any more luck with zoom instead of a scale transform, perhaps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

unfortunately not :/

CAn you create a runnable snippet which definitely shows the problem as at the moment I can't see a difference in what the two browsers are doing.
